# How to search list of numbers for a particular property

Tags: algorithm, math, computation

I have a long list of numbers.  There are no duplicates in the list and all numbers are representable with 2N bits.

For every pair of numbers, I can calculate whether a particular condition is true (whether the result of a bitwise XOR of the two numbers has exactly N bits set).  If the condition is true, I say those two numbers are linked.  I call the number of links a number has within a list its rank.  I need to find one of the numbers in the list that has the highest rank.

I can do this in O(n<sup>2</sup>) by calculating each number's rank one by one.

Is it possible to do it faster?

Comment: 1. Is each bit roughly equally likely to be set vs unset, or are some bits likely to be set vs unset? 2. Is there any correlation between bits (e.g. if the 3rd bit is set then the 8th bit is 80% likely to be set too). 3. Is there anything interesting about the numbers (e.g. sequences or patterns)

Comment: @Dave No, the numbers are essentially random.

Comment: For n items there are n.choose(2) pairings, which yields O(n^2) pairs to be evaluated. If someone can show a clever way to process O(n^2) distinct pairs with fewer than O(n^2) evaluations, I'll have learned something.

Comment: May we assume that N is constant? If so, how large will it roughly be?

Comment: @Luatic Yeah, N is constant

Comment: I guess one way to speed it up a bit is to group numbers by number of set bits in them. Then you do not have to pair any numbers with < N-k or > N+k bits with numbers that have less than k bits. This should eliminate some % of pairings, but still O(n²).

Comment: Actually `O(N^3)`. `xor` is a `O(N)` operation (with good constants)

Comment: @btilly O(n²N) you mean (don't confuse the two N's). Since Luke clarified that N is constant, this is just O(n²) though.

Comment: @Luatic You're right.

Comment: Given an arbitrary `a` in the list, it can be linked to any `b` s.t `a ^ b = z` which has exactly `N` set bits. So, you could first put the list of numbers into a hashmap, then for each number `a`, iterate over each length `2N` number with `N` bits set, `z`, then check how many `a ^ z` are in the map, which would be the rank of `a`. This would run in `n * (2N choose N)`, which can outperform the quadratic solution should `n` be really big and `N` very small. For reference, if `N` is 16 then `32 choose 16` is around 6 * 10^8.

Answer (score 1):

How many bit sequences will meet the `xor` condition for any given number?

From the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), it is `O(4^N/sqrt(N))`. More to the point, if I give you the first `2N-10*sqrt(N)` bits, odds are low that you can't conclude anything useful about whether it will meet your `xor` condition.

If `4^N < n`, we can get a speedup by just going with a data structure of number to count. Rather than look at each number to find whether it has a particular bitsequence that meets the `xor` condition, we just count how many times number meeting the condition appears. But if `n` is too much smaller than that, most numbers won't have enough other numbers close enough to them to try to benefit out of analyzing them as a group.

Comment: Not sure I understand all of that, but OP says numbers are representable in 2N bits and there are no duplicates, so I'd guess `n <= 2^2N`, right?

Comment: @tobias_k I missed the "no duplicates" line. Yes, that would imply that relationship. The fundamental problem here is connected to "the curse of dimensionality".